# Add Sortable Column For All Post Types

Tags: filters, wp-admin, columns

I am creating a hit counter that counts the number of page views across all post types. I have gotten it to work and the column displays for each post type showing the total number of page views. I was able to get the column to show up for every post type by using the following filter.

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posthit_columns');
```

I want to make this a portable column. I have gotten this to work for the main posts, post type, but i dont know how to make it show up for every post type without actually creating a filter for every post type.

The following filter will make the column sortable for the default post, but i have several post types and this isn't working. Is there a catch all filter for this?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'managesortablecolumns' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get all post_types and loop through them with the filter. This should work if the callback for all post types is the same (managesortablecolumns).

The code will look something like this:

```
function init_managesortablecolumns (){
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){
        add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $post_type . '_sortable_columns', 'managesortablecolumns' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'init_managesortablecolumns' );
```

BTW, if you store the post hit value in a custom field (post meta) you could use the [Admin Columns Pro plugin](http://www.admincolumns.com). This plugin has an interface for adding new columns to the overview with sorting, filtering and inline edit support.

Comment: good idea, but it doesnt seem to have worked for me. I have no way to check, but does get_post_types return anything in the init hook?

Comment: sorted the issue. Changed the priority of the init hook so that it loaded later. the custom posts were not loaded at the time that this init hook ran